# SQL Server: how to get a stored procedure to execute tsql from output

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I wanted to see if it's possible to create a SQL Server stored procedure to run a select statement, which will generate a list of rows/users as the result set. I then want the result set to be executed. All within the same stored procedure. Is that possible?

Here's the query I'm using:

```
SELECT 'REVOKE CONNECT FROM [' + name + '];' 
    from sys.sysusers 
    where hasdbaccess =1
    and name not in ('public','dbo','guest','sys')
    and hasdbaccess = 0 --0 = no access, 1 = access
    AND name LIKE 'RMT%'
```

This query may return 1-15+ rows of revoke connect commands.  example: `REVOKE CONNECT FROM [<AD>\RMTABC];`

I then would want the stored procedure to take that result set / output and execute the command/s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to execute your queries.

Note the following:

- Ensure you correctly escape object names by using `QUOTENAME`, not just by enclosing in `[]`.
- Any data which can be parameterized in a normal query can and should be passed through to `sp_executesql`, see the documentation. (Parameterization is important to avoid SQL injection issues.)
- `sys.sysusers` is deprecated and for compatibility only. Use `sys.database_principals` instead.
- The SQL variable should be `nvarchar(max)`, and any variables containing object names should be `sysname`, alias for `nvarchar(128)`.
- Your `hasdbaccess` conditions appear contradictory.

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(
  'REVOKE ' + dp.permission_name + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(u.name) + ';',
  '
')
FROM sys.database_principals u
JOIN sys.database_permissions dp ON u.principal_id = dp.grantee_principal_id
WHERE dp.major_id = 0
  AND dp.type = 'CO'  -- CONNECT permission
  AND dp.state IN ('G', 'W')  -- GRANT
  AND u.name NOT IN ('public', 'dbo', 'guest', 'sys')
  AND u.name LIKE 'RMT%';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: This helped. Thank you.